# WCF - Preventing Unauthorized Clients

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that I only want my applications to have access to. My applications consist of a traditional web interface that uses JQuery and a Silverlight interface. Neither of these interfaces require the user to login.

Is there a way that I can tell a WCF service to only allow clients that originated from my domain? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can - just require Windows credentials (i.e. an Active Directory account in your domain) from your callers.

Anyone not authenticated against your domain will be rejected.

You can do this by specifying either netTcpBinding with transport security (if everything is behind a corporate firewall), or wsHttpBinding with message security:

```
<bindings>
   <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="DomainUsersOnly">
         <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
         </security>
      </binding>
   </netTcpBinding>
   <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="HttpDomainUsersOnly">
         <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
         </security>
      </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Now, all you need to do is reference one of those binding configurations in your endpoints:

```
<endpoint name="whatever"
          address="......"
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="DomainUsersOnly"
          contract="IYourservice" />
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Careful here though - I think if a user has the same user name and password as a domain user (unlikely, I know) then they will be authenticated as the domain user.

Comment: no they won't - they need to have an actual Windows credential - a Windows security token from your domain - not just the same name by chance.

Comment: So how do you explain the third column on the table here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164725.aspx

Comment: when your client authenticates against a WCF using Windows credentials, it is not sending username/password - it's sending a Windows domain token - you can't fake that by having the same username/password as a domain user.

Comment: Marc is correct. You have to have an actual machine to machine trust established for windows credentials to work over WCF.

Comment: I have my service configured as you describe, and I ran WcfTestClient under the local Administrator account and connected to a local instance of my service. I expected it to deny access since the local Administrator account isn’t part of the domain but it still authenticated successfully (but using NTLM instead of Kerberos). This means that non-domain users can authenticate too. Any way to limit it to domain users only or limit it to Kerberos authentication only?

Answer (score 1):

If all of your legitimate users are supposed to be on your internal corporate LAN (on the same subnet), then you could lock it down by IP address using an approach like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFIPfilter.aspx). You could also clamp it down to several specific IP masks that way if you wanted to.

But if you want to allow legitimate users to hit it from anywhere, then this is not a good approach. Authentication would be better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a security restriction in IIS to only allow calls from the domain to the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you consider windows auth (since requests are coming from your domain), the preferred way to do this would be at a different level, via firewalls. At that level, you can restrict incoming traffic to a known set of IP addresses. This will only go so far, since IPs can be spoofed, but this is an open service, so there you go. A better alternative would be *both* firewalls and windows auth.

Alternatively, you could check client IP addresses in WCF by querying [`OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.incomingmessageproperties(VS.85).aspx).