# Secure WCF service from unauthorized use

Tags: c#, wcf, security

this is a similar question but doesn't fit my needs: [WCF - Preventing Unauthorized Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901712/wcf-preventing-unauthorized-clients)

I have full control over both a WCF Service and a number of clients that connect to this service.
Every client is just a program that doesn't require any username or password.

I want to be totally sure that **only my clients** will connect and use my WCF Service, is this possible?

My WCF Service uses 2 type of endpoints: `netTcpBinding` and `basicHttpBinding`.

Since i'm totally new to this kind of problem i'm googling and finding answer about using certificates, but i don't know if this is the right answer to my problem (and don't know of to use them). If certificates are the only way i'll use all the needed time to understand how to use them :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of authentication is required, which sort is very much context dependent.
If you're in a windows domain, I would suggest using those mechanisms. Either way you should probably start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx